# How to trigger event on HTML element in IE8?

Tags: javascript, html, events, internet-explorer-8, mouse

Below code works fine in Firefox, but not in IE8.

It triggers mouse click event on HTML element (here specified as 'node' ) and
invokes function already bound to that element.
So its like triggering the click event on given element programmatically.
 `var oEvent = document.createEvent( \"MouseEvents\" );
oEvent.initMouseEvent(\"click\", true, true, window, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, false, false, false, false, 0, node);
node.dispatchEvent(oEvent);`  
Can anybody help me to make it work in IE8 ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need code like that for Firefox on elements that did not already have a click event!

Just click the element in other browsers - for example node.click()

This means you need to sniff the event. I would try

```
if (node.click) node.click();
else if (document.createEvent) {
  var oEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  if (oEvent.initMouseEvent) { // just to be sure...
    oEvent.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, false, false, false, false, 0, node);  
    node.dispatchEvent(oEvent); 
  }
}
```

Comment: I have same issue. Could you help me for this? When I am trying to this code. its give node is undefined error.

Comment: I have ask question already.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20394182/checked-is-not-working-in-ie8-browser thank you